# Intellij. Srping boot 2.4.4 Why doesn't tak application.properties as default?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I just generate a spring boot project from https://start.spring.io/ and open it with intellj 2020.3.1 community edition.

I have changed the port at application.properties but nothing happens. I just create an application-default.properties file with the same port configuration and now it takes the port I set up properly.

any idea about why is ignoring application.properties file?

thank you very much.

Comment: Have you done a clean install in the mean time?

Comment: No really, I've just done but same result :(

Comment: Can you post what you have in your application.properties file